# Como adicionar mais campos à tabela de usuários com a gem Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Gostaria de saber se há possibilidade de adicionar mais campos a tabela de usuários gerada pelo Devise por que eu preciso relacionar ela com outras, e adicionar mais informações. Há algum problema em fazer assim?

Answer (score 2):

Não há nenhum problema, é uma tabela como qualquer outra.

Crie uma migration e adicione campos.

Answer (score 0):

Eu resolvi acrescentando estas linha no controller aplication

```
before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

protected

def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:nome])
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:ativo])
end
```